# sqlite db remains locked/unaccessible

Tags: c++, database, linux, sqlite

I have a problem with an sqlite3 db which remains locked/unaccessible after a certain access.

Behaviour occurs so far on Ubuntu 10.4 and on custom (OpenEmbedded) Linux.
The sqlite version is 3.7.7.1). Db is a local file.

One C++-applications accesses the db periodically (5s). Each time several insert statements are done wrapped in a deferred transaction. This happens in one thread only. The connection to the db is held over the whole lifetime of the application. The statements used are also persistent and reused via `sqlite3_reset`. sqlite_threadsafe is set to 1 (serialized), journaling is set to WAL.

Then I open in parellel the sqlite db with the sqlite command line tool. I enter `BEGIN IMMEDIATE;`, wait >5s, and commit with `END;`.

after this the db access of the application fails: the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` returns return code 1 ("SQL error or missing database"). If I execute an `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` right before the begin, just to be sure there is not already an active transaction, it fails with return code 5 ("The database file is locked").

Has anyone an idea how to approach this problem or has an idea what may cause it?

**EDIT:** There is a workaround: If the described error occures, I close and reopen the db connection. This fixes the problem, but I'm currently at a loss at to why this is so.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite is a server less database. As far as I know it does not support concurrent access from multiple source by design. You are trying to access the same backing file from both your application and the command tool - so you attempt to perform concurrent access. This is why it is failing.

Comment: It does support multiple accesses, but only if you've got the DB file on a filesystem that supports proper locks. On networked filesystems, it's really dodgy (and would be the same for any DB; networks and locks don't mix well).

Comment: @DonalFellows I stand corrected. Perhaps the needed file system locking is not configured in your custom kernel?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite connections should only be used from a *single thread*, as among other things they contain mutexes that are used to ensure correct concurrent access. (Be aware that SQLite also only ever supports a single updating thread at once anyway, and with no concurrent reads at the time; that's a limitation of being a server-less DB.)

Luckily, SQLite connections are relatively cheap when they're not doing anything and the cost of things like cached prepared statements is actually fairly small; open up as many as you need.

[EDIT]:
Moreover, this would explain closing and reopening the connection works: it builds the connection in the new thread (and finalizes all the locks etc. in the old one).

Comment: The question states that there are only two threads accessing the DB: One in the application and one in the command line tool. So each thread *has* its own connection.

Comment: @Hanno: It's not entirely obvious that that's so from the question, and the apparent solution fits the diagnosis…

Comment: I should also note that the constraint on threads and SQLite connections is actually that they can't be shared across threads *once any transaction has been started*. (Doing a SELECT or INSERT will do a transaction, even if not explicitly asked for.)